# C# Chart Axis Labels Not Formatting Properly

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, charts, async-await

Assume we have a method call that accesses a remote database, taking approximately 1 second to complete and returning a `DataTable` (simulated below):

```
DataTable GetData()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulated delay

    var dt = new DataTable("DataTable");
    dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));

    var rand = new Random();
    var date = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(date, rand.NextDouble() * 100);

        date = date.AddHours(12);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

The DataTable returned from this method is used to populate a `Chart` with a single line series. Why is it that this code shows correct, properly-formatted DateTime X-Axis labels:

```
async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = GetData();
    chart.DataSource = data;
    chart.DataBind();
}
```

[image: Chart with DateTime X-Axis]

and this code shows incorrect, unformatted X-Axis labels?

```
async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
    chart.DataSource = data;
    chart.DataBind();
}
```

[image: Chart with broken X-Axis]

Note that removing the `Thread.Sleep()` call also fixes this issue, even using the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer lies in `chart.Series[0].XValueType`

First, couple of statements:

1. `XValueType` is `Auto` by default, and, if it is not specified explicitly, being resolved to specific type somewhere before `Paint` event.

   It is not something obvious, I found it through decompiling sources; if you do want to follow my research, here are some milestones on the way:

   - `Chart` constructor:

     > `this._dataManager.Initialize();`
   - `DataManager.Initialize`:

     > `chartImage.BeforePaint += ChartPicture_BeforePaint`
   - `DataManager.ChartPicture_BeforePaint`
   - `DataManager.PrepareData`
   - `Series.PrepareData` =>

     > `if (this._xValueType == ChartValueType.Auto) { 
     >   this._xValueType = ChartValueType.Double;`
2. `DataBind` will try to resolve `Auto` to specific type based on `DataSource`. If it is *not* `Auto`, it will not respect data type in `DataSource`.

Ok, so what's happening in your sample:

1. When you don't use task, whole body of `Form_Load` executes synchronously; when you call `DataBind` on chart, it has `Auto` for `XValueType` and it is resolved to `DateTime` based on provide `DataSource`.
2. When you do use task with sleep, `Paint` event occurs before you initialize `DataSource`, which resolves `XValueType` to `Double`. When after that you bind DataSource, it uses float representation of `DateTime`.

How to fix all that mess? A lot of ways, but all of them based on chart value type:

- Specify value type explicitly in `Form_Load`
- Remove series and add new one exactly before `DataBind`
- Specify value type explicitly before `DataBind`
- ...